# Oracle Openscript and Javascript (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, oracle, openscript

I'm using Openscript on a form page that is using a clickable div  "save" button. When the button is clicked manually a javascript event is executed to save the changes on the page. When I play back the script, the script clicks on the button and gets redirected to the next page but does not save the changes I made on the text boxes. I'm guessing it doesnt run the ng-click updateUser() function when doing a playback. How can I get openscript to click on the save button and run the javascript function?

Openscript code:

```
web.button(
        "/web:window[@index='0' or @title=Payment Processor']/web:document[@index='0']/web:form[@name='form' or @index='0']/web:button[@index='1']")
        .click();
```

This is what the div save button code looks like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateUser()">
          <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>
           Save
       </button>

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.click();` should work, but you can try `mouseClick()` too.

Using OATS 12.4.0.1 and testing against the AnjularJS Docs example #64, I playback this similar ng-click to increment the displayed count. My example below shows with `mouseClick()`

- AnjularJS example #64:

  ```
  <body ng-app="">
    <button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
      Increment
    </button>
    <span>
      count: {{count}}
    </span>
  </body>
  ```
- Openscript code:

  ```
  web.window(2, "/web:window[@index='0']").navigate(
       "https://docs.angularjs.org/examples/example-example64/index.html");
  {
    think(14.929);
  }       
  web.button(4, "/web:window[@index='0']" 
          + "/web:document[@index='0']/web:button[@index='0']")
      .mouseClick(null, 1, false);
      // .click(); // this should work too.
  ```

Comment: Here is a working hosted example you can fork and edit to demo your example if you still have problems. [Plunker hosted link](http://plnkr.co/edit/DgXPqpUbJgh8iRt9xqLA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In OpenScript there is an option to call the JavaScript function directly.

```
String javaScript = "updateUser()";
DOMDocument doc = web.document("/web:window[@index='0' or @title=Payment Processor']/web:document[@index='0']/web:form[@name='form' or @index='0']");
doc.executeJavaScript(javaScript);
```

You can use the above code to call the JavaScript function.

Answer (score -1):

So far I never faced this issue that form is not getting saved or any other click is not saved..
just try following steps..

1. Record one more time a new script with save option
2. add proper think time

`think(8);` or some time I even do `think(8);think(8);` as some places openscript does not record any think time.

Actually I always increase think time after every step as uniform time 
`think(8);` after every single step even if some think time is there, add more and if no think time add some. The maximum is `think(10);`.